# Hide bus stations in google maps android api

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Android application that includes Google Maps api v2. However, there are lots of icons with bus/subway/train stations etc. which I do not want to appear in my app. Is there any possibility to remove/hide this icons?

Answer (score 3):

You can now remove labels and points of interest with Styling - available in the September 2016 release of the Google Maps Android API.

See a guide about how to do this here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features

See the release notes here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#september_21_2016

Answer (score 1):

**I'm using play-services-maps:12.0.1**

You can create your own style in [this page](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com).

Once it is done, click finish and copy the JSON. After that, replace this JSON in maps_style_json file in your android project.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This JSON deletes the landmarks and the labels, and just keeps the roads.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove these symbols as of this writing (3.2.65), but it has been already requested on [gmaps-api-issues #4841](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841).